# Filing Requirements for a Federal EIN

Tags: united-states, tax-law, irs

I am part of a university student organisation in Texas, and we have an EIN, a bank account, and a PayPal account. We only exist at one university, and are not affiliated or associated with any larger organisations except for the university department we're under. In any given year, we bring in about $2,000-$3,000 from dues payments, merchandise sales and whatever other fundraising we do. What are our tax or filing requirements?

I am asking this question because in 2018, a executive of the student organisation obtained our EIN and currently this is all that we possess: the EIN and nothing more, no articles of formation or whatever might've been provided. I don't know if we have been supposed to file taxes/other paperwork each year since then, or what our requirements in the future are. I don't know if there will be new requirements once we start to bring in more money each year. Is anyone able to point me to resources from the IRS to help? Let me know if you need any more information! I am also able to ask questions to the person who set up the EIN, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are an unincorporated non-profit organization which must file [IRS Form 990](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-990) or [IRS Form 990-EZ](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f990ez.pdf), if you must file any tax form. The thresholds for filing requirements are set forth in the instructions for those forms.

You must also withhold taxes from any employees (if any), file forms 1099 if you make sufficiently large payments to unincorporated independent contractors ($600 per vendor per year subject to some exceptions), and you probably have to pay sales tax on merchandise sales to state tax officials unless you get an exemption expressly recognized by the state.

Comment: Thanks! I'm assuming this wasn't filed for the organisation in 2019, what would I need to do to get up to date again, and what are the repercussions for having not filed it in 2019?

Comment: Also I don't think we have to pay sales tax because the merchandise that we sell, we buy from a 3rd party and pay sales tax at that point. So I think that falls under the "previously taxed items" exemption in Texas.

Comment: @Mr.King Probably a small fine at worst.